# Haskell: Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Text’

Tags: haskell

For some reason- *which I'm hoping to find out by virtue of asking this question*- having recently implemented a cadre of updates to a haskell script, including the addition of:

```
import System.Directory (doesFileExist, removeFile,getPermissions)
```

which serves to facilitate the following function:

```
validFile :: FilePath -> IO Bool
validFile path = do
    exists <- (doesFileExist path)
    if exists
    then (readable <$> getPermissions path)
    else return False
```

invoked as:

```
pwds <- case cfgPasswords of
    Just passPath -> do
         pathChecksOut <- validFile passPath
         when (not pathChecksOut) $ 
             errorL' ("Failed to access file at : " ++ passPath)
         (map (Just . T.unpack) . lines) <$> readFileUtf8 passPath
    Nothing       -> return $ replicate (length cfgPublicKeys) Nothing
```

I'm not able to anymore build the project on my machine.

The error I got was `Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Text’`, and it pointed me to the following line:

`errorL' ("Failed to access file at : " ++ passPath)`

It seems there's a question about StackOverflow that tries to address a similar issue, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37894987/couldnt-match-expected-type-text-with-actual-type-char). In an attempt to follow that advice I adapted the line like so `errorL' ("Failed to access file at : " ++ (passPath :: Text))`, but still I wan't able to build the project.

The exact console output I received after implementing the changes you recommend in your last post looks like this:

[image]

The full file and the progress of adding this feature (rather *bug*!) is well encapsulated in [this gist file](https://gist.github.com/s-matthew-english/41e18c23d34009bd7b69ed925b4ed2d8).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert from a `String` (which is what `FilePath` is) to a `Text` you need to explicitly use `pack`: a type annotation alone won't do.

You will also need to use `append` (or `Monoid`'s `(<>)`) instead of `(++)` which is list specific.

Comment: cool- thank you for your help! could you maybe show me how that would look like? I'm still really new to haskell

Comment: I thought `<>` got moved to Semigroup?

Answer (score 2):

```
when (not pathChecksOut) .
    errorL' . T.pack $ "Failed to access file at : " ++ passPath
```

As the error message says, "the first argument of `errorL'`" is "Expected type:  `Text`", but you have passed an "Actual type: `FilePath`".  In this particular case, you want to convert, so you hoogle for `FilePath -> Text` and if that doesn't find what you want you remember that `FilePath` is a type alias and hoogle for `String -> Text` also.

Comment: man might have that fixed it- but now I'm getting an error that this line `then (readable <$> getPermissions path)` in the function of the OP, is `Variable not in scope` :/

Comment: You were already getting it (look at your screenshot) and the error message tells you exactly what you need to do: add it to the import list of `System.Directory`.