# Could not match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Data.Text.Internal.Text’

Tags: haskell, pandoc

This seems like a popular question. I am not familiar with Haskell at all, so by reading the answers to the similar questions I can't really understand what needs to be done in my case.

My script looks like this:

```
import Text.Pandoc.JSON

pagebreakXml :: String
pagebreakXml = "<w:p><w:r><w:br w:type=\"page\"/></w:r></w:p>"

pagebreakBlock :: Block
pagebreakBlock = RawBlock (Format "openxml") pagebreakXml

blockSwapper :: Block -> Block
blockSwapper (Para [Str "<div class=\"docxPageBreak\"></div>"])  = pagebreakBlock
blockSwapper blk = blk

main = toJSONFilter blockSwapper
```

Compiling it results in these errors:

```
$ ghc --make docx-page-filter.hs -package-db=/Users/eugene/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3/package.db
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( docx-page-filter.hs, docx-page-filter.o )

docx-page-filter.hs:7:35: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Data.Text.Internal.Text’
                  with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the first argument of ‘Format’, namely ‘"openxml"’
      In the first argument of ‘RawBlock’, namely ‘(Format "openxml")’
      In the expression: RawBlock (Format "openxml") pagebreakXml
  |
7 | pagebreakBlock = RawBlock (Format "openxml") pagebreakXml
  |                                   ^^^^^^^^^

docx-page-filter.hs:7:46: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Data.Text.Internal.Text’
      Expected type: Data.Text.Internal.Text
        Actual type: String
    • In the second argument of ‘RawBlock’, namely ‘pagebreakXml’
      In the expression: RawBlock (Format "openxml") pagebreakXml
      In an equation for ‘pagebreakBlock’:
          pagebreakBlock = RawBlock (Format "openxml") pagebreakXml
  |
7 | pagebreakBlock = RawBlock (Format "openxml") pagebreakXml
  |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^

docx-page-filter.hs:10:25: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Data.Text.Internal.Text’
                  with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the pattern: "<div class=\"docxPageBreak\"></div>"
      In the pattern: Str "<div class=\"docxPageBreak\"></div>"
      In the pattern: [Str "<div class=\"docxPageBreak\"></div>"]
   |
10 | blockSwapper (Para [Str "<div class=\"docxPageBreak\"></div>"])  = pagebreakBlock
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
$
```

At first, I went with an accepted answer suggested here: [Couldn't match expected type `Text' with actual type `[Char]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37894987/couldnt-match-expected-type-text-with-actual-type-char). It helped reduce the number of errors to a single one. Compiling the script now results in this error that I don't know how to fix:

```
$ ghc --make docx-page-filter.hs -package-db=/Users/eugene/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3/package.db -XOverloadedStrings
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( docx-page-filter.hs, docx-page-filter.o )

docx-page-filter.hs:7:46: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Data.Text.Internal.Text’
      Expected type: Data.Text.Internal.Text
        Actual type: String
    • In the second argument of ‘RawBlock’, namely ‘pagebreakXml’
      In the expression: RawBlock (Format "openxml") pagebreakXml
      In an equation for ‘pagebreakBlock’:
          pagebreakBlock = RawBlock (Format "openxml") pagebreakXml
  |
7 | pagebreakBlock = RawBlock (Format "openxml") pagebreakXml
  |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
$
```

What should I change about my code to fix this issue?

Comment: Which version of the compiler are you using ? Using ghci v8.6.5, I get this as the type signature for RawBlock: `RawBlock :: Format -> String -> Block` and your code works out of the box. In any case, you can use function [pack](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v:pack) to convert from String to Text.

Comment: @jpmarinier pandoc finally made the switch from String to Text in version 2.8. You probably have an older version installed.

Comment: More of a side comment: instead of using a Haskell filter, one could also adjust [this](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/pagebreak) Lua filter. This would avoid some data serialization and could be a bit faster.

Comment: @tarleb Correct, running Pandoc 2.5 as provided by Linux Fedora v31. So apparently they are not above breaking backward compatibility.

Comment: @tarleb as I understand, that Lua filter works only on Latex files. I made a couple of attempts to adjust it, but it just won't accept HTML as an input. Any idea why?

Comment: @gmile That's true, it's mostly aimed at Markdown input (which may include raw LaTeX). I'm happy to see from your post to the pandoc issue that you found a way to adapt it to you requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Haskell there are multiple types of strings in common usage. By default, string literals (`"stuff in quotes"`) are of type `String` (which is `[Char]`), but the library you're using expects values of type `Text`.

- Enable the `OverloadedStrings` extension so that string literals can also have type `Text`
- Change the type signature(s) from `String` to `Text`; `Text` can be imported from the `Data.Text` module in the *text* library (it's also worth mentioning that there are two `Text`, the other one from `Data.Text.Lazy`, and that could be another source of mismatch for you in the future).

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}   -- Add at the top of the file

...  -- imports
import Data.Text (Text)              -- Import the Text type

pagebreakXml :: Text                 -- from String to Text
pagebreakXml = "<w:p>..."
```